# Запрет регистрации с определённых доменов (отрицание в регулярных выражениях)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть выражение такого вида:

```
".*@*\\.(?<!domain)com$"
```

суть его такова: разрешение или запрет регистрации с определенных доменов.

если я все правильно написал, то если у человека мыло user@example.com, то он пройдет, а если user@domain.com - то нет, верно?

Comment: А почему `@*` т.е. от 0 и более собак и сразу за ними почему то точка. и перед com почему то точки нет ... вообще есть http://regex101.com ставьте в настройках python и тестируйте выражение

Comment: @Mike
".*@*(?<!domain).com$"

Comment: `p = re.compile(r'.*@(?!example\.com|other\.prohibited\.com)')`